Gradle tests failing with MessageIOException
Getting the following error:
org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not write '/127.0.0.1:56257'.

at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.flush(SocketConnection.java:134)

at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionDispatch.run(MessageHub.java:325) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent ExecutorPolicy CatchAndRecord Failures.onExecute(Executor Policy.java:63)

at org.gradle.internal.concurrent. Managed ExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
....

My application is not trying to connect to any local host, but gradle test command is failing with this error.
Gradle version used: 4.2
And when I try running the each tests, none are failing.
Is it an issue related to gradle version?
